# Can Struts2 s:select get the list from an indirect object?

Tags: forms, list, struts2

I have a struts2 selection list that I'd like the list to come from a 'sub' object, the same way that the 'name' can be set to a 'sub' object. This code works :

```
<s:select name="person.town" id="ddlTown" list="towns"/>
```

My form object has a 'person' Object attribute and a 'towns' List attribute. So when the form is displayed, form.getTowns() is called to populate the selection list, and when the form is submitted, the form instantiates a Person object and then calls Person.setTown() to set the value.

What I want is something like this :

```
<s:select name="person.town" id="ddlTown" list="listholder.towns"/>
```

So that when the form is displayed, form.getListholder().getTowns() is called to populate the selection list. But I get the error :

```
The requested list key 'listholder.towns' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map...
```

Is there any way to do this so that my form object doesn't directly have to contain all my list objects?

*** EDIT  ***

Andrea Ligios and others : Sorry for the confusion. Yes, form means 'action', I've called it 'form' because because the tag is

```
<s:form action="addperson_act" method="post" id="addperson_form" name="addperson_form"
```

but its really a ***mypkg.addPersonAct*** object. There are over 10 drop down lists on this form, so I have

```
class mypkg.AddPersonAct {
    List<String> towns;
    List<String> states;
    List<String> countys;
    List<String> countrys;
    . . .
```

etc. with all getters/setters. The problem is that these 10+ lists (and 20+ getters/setters) are duplicated in 2 other action/form objects because of the way this application is structured, so its messy and more work to make changes. What I want to do is have an object that holds all these lists :

```
class AddPersonLists {
    List<String> towns;
    List<String> states;
    List<String> countys;
    List<String> countrys;
    . . .
```

with all getters/setters. This way, the 3 action/form objects only need ONE attribute and getter :

```
class mypkg.AddPersonAct {
    private AddPersonList listHolder;

    public getListHolder {
        return listHolder;
    }
```

So these lists, how they are instantiated, and getters/setter methods are contained in ONE object, not duplicated in 3.

FYI : I haven't done web development before and inherited this code and the way its structured. Having 3 Action objects with all the same attributes seems wrong, but I don't have time to rework/restructure the way this app works.

Comment: It's not clear what list objects you want your form object _doesn't directly have to contain all your list objects_.

Comment: What *form* object are you talking about?

Comment: Show your code, this is very confusing. *Form* means Action ? is `listholder` a `List<Holder>` where `Holder` is an object containing an attribute `towns` that is a `List<Town>` ?

Comment: How do you populate your lists?

Comment: The lists are populated from database queries.

Comment: Check that list are populated, that you have all getters and setters in action class and in your `listHolder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

In Action you have `AddPersonAct.java`

```
public class AddPersonAct {
private AddPersonLists listHolder;

public void setListHolder(AddPersonLists listHolder) {
    this.listHolder = listHolder;
}

public AddPersonLists getListHolder() {
    return listHolder;
}
}
```

In Action class

```
private AddPersonAct addpersonact;
//getter
//setter
```

In jsp

```
<s:select name="person.town" id="ddlTown" list="addpersonact.getListHolder().getTowns()"/>
```

Comment: Wow - that works!! list="addpersonact.getListHolder().getTowns() - I even managed to pass a parameter using #session.XXX and it passed through to the code!

Comment: **list="addpersonact.getListHolder().getTowns()** - I even managed to pass a parameter using #session.XXX and it passed through to the code! Now where is there documentation that says these lists can use real method calls? Thank you very much!

Comment: [See full page click here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Collection_Construction)